# Using Ternary Expressions in Running ETL from Sybase to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ternary-operator

I am running an ETL to pull data from sybase into a MongoDB environment. Initially my ETL design for a value looked like this:

```
hireDate: data.hire_date ? data.hire_date : null
```

But, while this works, it also populates a null to the database when the value doesn't exist in the original doc.

A long-form conditional expression will work, like this:

```
if (data.hire_date) staffProfile.hireDate = data.hire_date;
```

But I'd like to make this as succinct as possible, and use a ternary expression to handle this in the same line of code as where I assign the value.

Now, because I don't want to populate a bunch of nulls to the database, I am attempting to use ternary expressions in such a way as to just skip the doc field if it is `undefined`, like what's happening in the long-form "if" conditional expression above. However, what I tried isn't working. My ETL errors when a doc contains an `undefined` value. Here is the relevant section of code I tried:

```
Staff.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    legacyId: data.id_number
  },
  {
    $set: {
      staffProfile: {
        hireDate: data.hire_date ? (hireDate = data.hire_date) : null,
        vtrNum: data.vtr_num ? (vtrNum = data.vtr_num) : null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    returnNewDocument: true
  }
);
```

What am I missing here? Is there a way to do this evaluation and assignment all in one line like I'm attempting to do here?

Comment: Shouldn't your ternary expression look like this: `data.hire_date ? data.hire_date : null` ? Right now you will probably set `hireDate` to `true` or `null`?

Comment: No, because that will populate a null to the database. That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Your problem isn't the part behind the `?`but the part behind the `:` which is evaluated when your condition fails. So when `data.hire_date` does not exist you will set `hireDate` to `null`. Replace `null` with something that's ok. Empty String maybe? Edit: You do not need an else so you should not use an ternary expression. Just use an if.

Comment: Using an empty string will still populate that to the database -- which isn't what you want in a MongDB environment. If the value doesn't exist, the field shouldn't be there in the document -- period. Ideally it shouldn't contain an empty string, or a null.

Comment: Yes, you are right with that. To fix your problem don't use the ternary expression. You do not need an 'else' part so just use an if. Or something like `(data.hire_date && (hireDate=date.hire_date))`... I would use an if.

Comment: But that's far less succinct. I added more info above to point out that I did that originally. Please see my added details above. There should be a way to do this with a ternary expression.

Comment: Removed my answer. You should use the if. It won't look any better if you don't.

Comment: Again, it's not about it "looking better", it's about succinctly getting it into one line of code where the assignment takes place.